# What's the best way to intermingle code within lists?

Tags: support, bug

Nothing critical about this question, but let's say I have a query...

```
select *
from table
where formatting = 'well-nigh';
```

*NOTE:* I'm including some screenshots from [dba.se.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) as I don't think [dba.meta.se.com](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com) sets color within code blocks, by default.

*<screenshot with proper coloring taken from [dba.se.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com)>*

[image]

*</screenshot>*

... and I want to include it within a list of instructions:

1. Try this query
2. Or try this query

How do I intermingle these two markup items so they are formatted properly together?  I'm not seeing a way to do it within the [editing help page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/editing-help), and none of the ways I've tried are able to render the list and include the code (*with proper coloring*) appropriately.

Here are examples of what I've attempted so far.  For instance, the following code mashes both markdown approaches together without much finesse...

```
1. Try this query:

    select *
    from table
    where formatting = 'well-nigh';

2.  Or try this query:

    select *
    from table
    where formatting = 'well-nigh';
```

...which results with the list rendering properly, but not the code:

1. Try this query:

   select *
   from table
   where formatting = 'well-nigh';
2. Or try this query:

   select *
   from table
   where formatting = 'well-nigh';

I could nest the code within backticks (`)...

```
1. Try this query:

    `select *
    from table
    where formatting = 'well-nigh';`

2.  Or try this query:

    `select *
    from table
    where formatting = 'well-nigh';`
```

..but it doesn't do so well with multi-line code-blocks nor does this approach render the color properly either:

1. Try this query:

   `select *
   from table
   where formatting = 'well-nigh';`
2. Or try this query:

   `select *
   from table
   where formatting = 'well-nigh';`

So I'm left with `<pre>`...

```
1. Try this query:<pre>select *
    from table
    where formatting = 'well-nigh';</pre>
2. Or try this query:<pre>select *
    from table
    where formatting = 'well-nigh';</pre>
```

...which may be the saving grace here...

1. Try this query:

   ```
   select *
   from table
   where formatting = 'well-nigh';
   ```
2. Or try this query:

   ```
   select *
   from table
   where formatting = 'well-nigh';
   ```

...**BUT** the `<pre>` elements do not enable the coloring like I would get within a normal (indented) code block, which you can see from the following screenshot:

*<screenshot with (lack of) coloring taken from [dba.se.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com)>*

[image]

*</screenshot>*

I'm fine sticking with the `<pre>` tags whenever I want to take this approach within a post, but is there a better way to do this that retains the formatting of the list items and code and also includes the appropriate coloring?

Final note on this: I'm posting this on [dba.meta.se.com](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com) instead of [meta.se.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com) as I believe the markdown parsers differ between the various SE communities, but please let me know if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need more indentation :)

This:

```
1. Try this query:

        select *
        from table
        where formatting = 'well-nigh';

2.  Or try this query:

        select *
        from table
        where formatting = 'well-nigh';
```

Produces:

1. Try this query:

   ```
   select *
   from table
   where formatting = 'well-nigh';
   ```
2. Or try this query:

   ```
   select *
   from table
   where formatting = 'well-nigh';
   ```

Comment: Who knew *more white-space* was the answer to anything?!?  Thanks!

Comment: This frustrates me because the extra indentation is not obvious and there isn't an easy way to apply it with the toolbar and keyboard shortcuts AFAIK.